# Trick behind JVM's compressed Oops

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

So I understand the compressed oops is enabled by default in HotSpot VM now. It has support for this from Java SE 6u23 onwards through the VM option `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`. I understand that it allows for efficient CPU cache utilization as the CPU caches can hold a larger number of references than if they had to deal with 64 bit sized references. But what I do not understand is how using only 32 bits JVM can address up to 2<sup>64</sup> addresses.

To simplify the problem  how can we address up to 2<sup>4</sup> memory address's using just 2 bits? What can be a possible encoding/decoding of such an address scheme?

Comment: Hint: CompressedOops is limited to 2^35 addresses, not 2^64.

Answer (score 37):

For a detailed explanation of compressed oops, see the ["Compressed oops in the Hotspot JVM"](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops) article by John Rose @ Oracle.

The TL;DR version is:

- on modern computer architectures, memory addresses are byte addresses,
- Java object references are addresses that point to the start of a word<sup>1</sup>,
- on a 64-bit machine, word alignment means that that the bottom 3 bits of an object reference / address are zero<sup>2</sup>
- so, by shifting an address 3 bits to the right, we can "compress" up to a 35 bits of a 64 bit address into a 32-bit word,
- and, decompression can be done by shifting 3 bits to the left, which puts those 3 zero bits back,
- 35 bits of addressing allows us to represent object pointers for up to 32 GB of heap memory using compressed oops that fit in 32-bit (half-)words on a 64-bit machine.

---

Note that this **only** works on a 64-bit JVM.  We still need to be able to address the memory containing that (up to) 32 GB heap<sup>1</sup>, and that means 64-bit hardware addresses (on modern CPUs / computer architectures).

Note also that there is a small penalty in doing this; i.e. the shift instructions required to translate between regular and compressed references.  However, the flip side is that less actual memory is consumed<sup>3</sup>, and memory caches are typically more effective as a consequence.

<sup>1 - This is because modern computer architectures are optimized for word-aligned memory access.</sup>

<sup>2 - This assumes that you haven't used `-XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes` to increase the alignment from its default (and minimum) value of 8 bytes.</sup>

<sup>3 - In fact, the memory saving is application specific.  It depends on the average object alignment wastage, ratios of reference to non-reference fields and so on.  It gets more complicated if you consider tuning the object alignment.</sup>

---

> To simplify the problem how can we address up to 2<sup>4</sup> memory addresses using just 2 bits? What can be a possible encoding/decoding of such an address scheme?

You can't address 2<sup>4</sup> byte addresses.  But you *can* address 2<sup>2</sup> word addresses (assuming 32-bit words) using 2-bit word addresses.  If you can assume that all byte addresses are word-aligned, then you can compress a 4-bit byte address as 2-bit word address by shifting it by 2-bit positions.

Comment: I do not follow the logic "on a 64bit machine, that means that that the bottom 3 bits of an address are zero". Why would the fact that references point the start of a word lead to a situation that the bottom 3 bits are all `0`s?

Comment: Because modern computer architectures are byte addressed.

Comment: Got it. I am also having trouble understanding what exactly you meant by "so, by shifting an address 3 bits to the left, we can "compress" up to a 35 bits of a 64 bit address into a 32 bit word,".. How did you arrive at the number 35?

Comment: Simple arithmetic.  32 + 3 == 35.

Comment: Not sure I get it : the 35 bits of get is 32 bits plus 3 bits sets to 0. You don't add space by having more zero, if such bits have to be 0... I am sure I am missing something in the reasoning but it just sounds funny...

Comment: So it's not so much that you gain 3 bits but rather that you avoid loosing them really ...

Comment: I wonder why they didn't pick 16-byte alignment? Most applications don't use a lot of bare objects with no fields; even a single boolean field will bump the object size up to 16 bytes.

Comment: You have to measure across all objects in the JVM.  I imagine that they did this ... across a range of real-world applications ... and determined that 16 byte alignment resulted in too much wasted space.  There is a trade-off between space used by large refs and space used due to object address alignment.

Comment: Besides, the alignment decision would have most likely been made 10+ years earlier ... and baked in.

Comment: @StephenC fair point, I wasn't considering objects whose 8-byte-aligned sizes weren't 16-byte-aligned (e.g. 24, 40, 56, ...) and thus would waste more space under my scheme

Comment: One possible argument for 8-byte alignment rather than 16-byte alignment is that it makes converting to an absolute address cheaper. On x86-64, scale by 8 and add to base address can be done with a single `LEA` instruction. If you want to scale by 16 instead, you cannot do it with a single `LEA`. I do not know if this actually factored into the decision though.

Answer (score 9):

It's not meant for 32-bit JVMs. It's to alleviate the additional overhead that occur in 64-bit JVMs. I think Oracle's page explains it well:

> Compressed Oops
>
> Compressed oops represent managed
>   pointers (in many but not all places in the JVM software) as 32-bit
>   object offsets from the 64-bit Java heap base address. Because they're
>   object offsets rather than byte offsets, they can be used to address
>   up to four billion objects (not bytes), or a heap size of up to about
>   32 gigabytes. To use them, they must be scaled by a factor of 8 and
>   added to the Java heap base address to find the object to which they
>   refer.

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html)

Answer (score 4):

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/35gb-heap-less-32gb-java-jvm-memory-oddities/

I think this article explain this well. Taken away:

> Because the JVM memory layout uses a 8byte addressing scheme, which means that objects can be at address 0, 8, 16, 24… but not at 2, 7 or any other non multiple of 8, compressed oops just address the virtual positions 0, 1, 2, 3 instead of the real ones 0, 8, 16, 24. To get from the compressed address to the real one, the JVM needs just to left shift it 3 times. Easy.

4G * 8 = 32

Answer (score 1):

[CompressedOops](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops).

From the article:
Not all of the pointers are compressed, and the compressed ones are 32-bit values which must be scaled by a factor of 8 and added to a 64-bit base address to find the object they refer to.

Now note that you can't address 2^64 bits of memory with these 32bit pointers, but you can access plenty of `Objects` with them. If you have an object at memory location `x`, there's no way that you can have another one at `x+1`. That's why you don't need to access every single memory location.